# How do you tail oozie job logs?

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I typically check logs with this command:

```
 $ oozie job -oozie http://localhost:8080/oozie -log 14-20090525161321-oozie-joe
```

This will print everything. However I want to only see the last few lines.

How can i tail oozie job logs?

Thanks

Comment: any reason why piping the above through `tail` isn't an acceptable solution for you?

Answer (score 6):

As Chris suggested above use this to print last 10 lines

```
$ oozie job -oozie oozie_URL -log job_ID | tail -n 10
```