# Whats the best way to log in oozie

Tags: oozie

We are using oozie workflows with a oozie main class in the action. I am not really sure what is the best logging strategy. Should we just use log4j since it seems like that is the default strategy ? Do those logs get collected on the data nodes ?

Answer (score 0):

> Should we just use log4j since it seems like that is the default
>   strategy ?

I have not found any mention of someone using an alternative logger. It seems to [be discouraged](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/AG_OozieLogging.html#Other_Oozie_Logging):

> While Oozie can technically use any valid log4j Appender or
>   configurations that violate the above restrictions, certain features
>   related to logs may be disabled and/or not work correctly, and is thus
>   not advised.

Your other question:

> Do those logs get collected on the data nodes ?

An [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14195797/1587329) mentions that

> the logs are distributed across your cluster, but by logging them to
>   the rootLogger, you should be able to see them via the job tracker (by
>   drilling down on the Job task attempts).

You can [inspect them via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918706/how-do-you-tail-oozie-job-logs)

> use this to print last 10 lines
>
> ```
> $ oozie job -oozie oozie_URL -log job_ID | tail -n 10
> ```